# ICO takes forever to load

Tags: html

How do I tell a webpage that I don't want an ICO so it doesn't waste loadtime looking for it??

```
<link rel="icon" type="images/png" href="" />
```

If it's omitted, then it looks too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add the following to your apache config

```
Redirect 404 /favicon.ico
```

Comment: Um... How does this differ from the default behaviour?

Comment: Also, your question didn't specify the context "on my own local browser+same local webserver" - this solution solves a problem that is **completely different** from the one you asked (namely - based on your comment to my question - "how to stop your own web server from wasting time doing complicated long logic involved in my server's general 404 processing, when that 404 is for a favicon". It does NOT solve a problem that most people would interpret your question as - which is "how do I prevent a web user's browser from asking for favicon from my server and and my server from answering 404

Answer (score 5):

Hmm... One possible trick could be to point it to LOCAL location:

```
<link rel="icon" type="images/png" href="http://127.0.0.1/no_icon.ico" />
```

It will still look, but 127.0.0.1 is by definition local host so there's no network trip involved to discover that there's nothing to load.

From [RFC 5735: Special-Use IPv4 Addresses](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735.txt):

> 127.0.0.0/8 - This block is assigned for use as the Internet host
>      loopback address.  A datagram sent by a higher-level protocol to an
>      address anywhere within this block loops back inside the host.  This
>      is ordinarily implemented using only 127.0.0.1/32 for loopback.  As
>      described in [RFC1122], Section 3.2.1.3, addresses within the entire
>      127.0.0.0/8 block **do not legitimately appear on any network anywhere**.

Comment: ..and all the developers out there that actually have a localhost wonder why they suddenly start getting 404's for a file they don't have or reference.  +1 for pandemonium that ensues.

Comment: That may work in some cases, but it isn't always local, ie. on my dev server. It would be best if it was an elegant solution that had global application :P

Comment: @Kirk - can you please clarify how you have 127.0.0.1 to be not local considering it's against the RFC? Please see the update in the answer.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but it still isn't elegant. For example, my .htaccess sends it to a not-found page where it says the database is having a connection issue, therefore It's having to look at resources ( not instant ). Did you see the answer I stumbled across below? I think that may be the best way to go??

Comment: @Kirk - I am pretty certain you can adjust .htaccess to make a special case for this URL on your dev server. P.S. I like the "fake protocol" idea though you will first need to research to see if all browsers will treat it as "don't make a request" in case of LINK REL as opposed to "default to favicon HTTP" before employing it.

Answer (score 1):

Many browsers will simply look for http://yoursite.com/favicon.ico by default, without any prompt.  Unfortunately, there's not a lot you can do to stop browsers from requesting that file, since it's setting controlled by the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bogus protocol that the browser won't recognize.  Then it will simply do nothing:

```
<link rel="icon" type="images/png" href="ignoreme://i-dont-want-no-stinkin/favicon.ico" />
```

:-)

Comment: I'm +1-ing this for wacky brilliance, but you need to verify that this approach would NOT cause some browser to fall back on default favicon.